# where statements with groupby in python dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by, where-clause

```
train[['Pclass', 'Age']].groupby(['Pclass'], as_index=False).median().sort_values(by='Pclass', ascending=True)
```

This is the bit where I am doing the grouping, finding the summary statistics, and sorting it based on a column ('Pclass' in this case).

How can I use a where clause along with this? The where clause I want to enter would perform something similar to `train[train.Survived==1]`

Any thoughts on how this can be achieved? I am using the classic "Titanic" dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `train[['Pclass', 'Age']]` to

```
train.loc[train['Survived'] == 1, ['Pclass', 'Age']]
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
train = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

print(train.loc[train['survived'] == 1, ['pclass', 'age']]
           .groupby(['pclass'], as_index=False)
           .median()
           .sort_values(by='pclass', ascending=True))
```

prints

```
   pclass   age
0       1  35.0
1       2  28.0
2       3  22.0
```